# How to make sure that long lines are displayed full (without truncation) in Org Mode?

Tags: org-mode

Imagine I have a line that is longer than the available space. I want this one physical line to be displayed as multiple ones (so that I can see it in full without scrolling). In the screenshot below you see one logical line displayed as two (red rectangle):

[image: Screenshot 1]

When I open the same file in Emacs, Org mode, type `:vsp`, then that same line is truncated:

[image: Screenshot 2]

**How can I make sure that this line is displayed in Emacs like it is in Vim** (see screenshot above)?

I tried the following:

1. Adding `(setq-default truncate-lines nil)` to `.emacs` file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879838/399457) (then restarting Emacs).
2. `M-x auto-fill-mode` or `M-x fill-region` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879910/399457).

None of this helped.

Comment: Please read this question/answer: https://superuser.com/questions/299886/linewrap-in-org-mode-of-emacs

Answer (score 4):

Click on `Options / Line wrapping in this buffer / Wrap at window edge` to change it for the current buffer.

To change it on a permanent basis, you will need to search your initialization file(s) for `truncate-lines`: somebody must be setting it to `t` for Org mode buffers. You will need to change that setting to `nil`. If it only happens on partial-width windows (as shown in your screenshots), you might want to look at `truncate-partial-width-windows` as Jean Pierre points out in a comment. Setting both of these variables to nil (and making sure that nobody overrides those settings) will ensure that lines are wrapped always.

Here's the doc string for `truncate-lines`:

> truncate-lines is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.
>     Calls these functions when changed: (#)
>     This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>     satisfies the predicate ‘booleanp’.
>     You can customize this variable.
>     Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 1.7.
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means do not display continuation lines.
>   Instead, give each line of text just one screen line.
>
> Note that this is overridden by the variable
>   ‘truncate-partial-width-windows’ if that variable is non-nil
>   and this buffer is not full-frame width.
>
> Minibuffers set this variable to nil.

Comment: Note that the standard default value for `truncate-partial-width-windows` is 50, so this may need to be changed too.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited the answer a bit.